# last index using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a recursive function lastIndex() that takes a list and a value as a parameter returns the index of the last occurrence of the value in the list.  If the value is cannot be found in the list or the list is empty, then the function returns -1.  The function must be recursive and the list provided as a parameter may not be modified. Example:

```
>>>lastIndex([1,2,3,4,5,1],1)
5
>>>lastIndex([1,4,7,2,3,2],3)
4
```

My current code:

```
def lastIndex(lst,n):
    if lst[0] ==n:
        return -1
    else:
        1 + lastIndex(lst[1:],n)
```

Comment: Normally, I'm more forgiving with my voting. But, today, you have asked *several* homework questions in a row, in rapid succession. Your "current code" in each case shows only a minimal attempt at a solution, and it's clear you haven't attempted to test the code at all. Given that it's homework, I expect that you would spend at least a bit more time to think about each one.

Comment: Or you could just do your own homework :) It's really not very hard

Comment: I have spent over 2 hours pondering these questions, so I posted them all in a row because many of them are similar. I do not understand recursion as easily it seems as all of you, that is why I came here for help, I don't need a direct answer, just a push in the right direction would do.

Comment: 2 hours is not actually a long time, considering the sheer number of questions you've asked. It takes a long time to understand recursion; a few "gimme" answers on SO will not help you much. If you're trying to do your homework at the last minute, well, tough luck.

Comment: In fact this question is a duplicate. Has been asked sometimes back.

Comment: If you look, all my question pertain to recursion, and nothing else. If I wanted you to do all my HW i would just post it all, not just portions.

Comment: I found that link, and none of the answers helped me understand what they did.

Comment: You seem to have the same indentation problem in all your posts as well.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my answer to your previous homework question, recursion consists of two things:

- A base case
- A way to base an answer for a problem off the answer to a closer-to-base problem

In this case, the base case you're probably looking for is an empty list.

The way to tie the problem to a smaller problem is to break your input list into two pieces: the last element of the input, and the list of elements before the last element. The list of elements before the last element is your smaller problem; the last element is how you decide whether you need to solve the smaller problem or not.

---

Consider this set of questions:

- Is the last element of my input the element I'm looking for? If so, how many elements are before it?
- Otherwise, what's the answer to the above set of questions if I remove the current last element and try again?

In this case, recursion is the 'try again'.

Comment: OP:  Reread the last sentence of this answer.  Your code finds the *first* occurance, not the last.  It essentially attacks the problem from the wrong end.

Comment: Thanks. I read that last time. Do i go down the list like the other problems I had? If so How do I go down a lst?

Comment: or up if im reading Stevens advice correctly?

Comment: Recursive function calls will "go down the list" for you, as long as you're reducing the number of elements you're looking at each time.

Comment: im not sure if I follow. again i apologize for sounding incompetent, I just really need to understand this concept.

Comment: Try this smaller problem first, then: can you write a function `foo(some_list)` that prints out a list in the reverse order from which it was input, using only three things: the `print` statement, the function `foo()`, and list indexing (e.g. `some_list[some_position]`?

Comment: Also @JasonSchayer if you'd like some more real-time help, feel free to join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18443/help-with-recursion within the next few minutes.

Comment: ya but without recursion

Comment: Still can't, maybe just takes a while to update

Comment: Hm. Make sure you don't have an adblocker running or similar. The text entry box should be in the lower left corner.

Comment: You might also need to leave the room and re-join it (via the 'leave' link above the avatars).

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It is tail recursive.

```
>>> def lastIndex(lst,n,c=None):
...     if c is None:
...        c = len(lst)-1
...     if c < 0:
...         return -1
...     elif lst[c] == n:
...         return c
...     else:
...         return lastIndex(lst, n, c-1)
... 
>>> lastIndex([1,2,3,4,5,1],1)
5
>>> lastIndex([1,4,7,2,3,2],3)
4
```

Comment: `if c < 0:` is better written as `if not c:`, and since this is homework, its not always prudent to solve the problem for the OP - especially since they asked for a hint.

Comment: Sorry Dan thanks for the help, but Id rather get a hint

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `not c` is `True` for `c == 0` while `c < 0` is `False` and `not c` is `False` for `c == -1` while `c < 0` is `True`. In this case it would be an error to rewrite the condition that way.

Answer (score -1):

```
def lastindex(lst, what_to_find, start_length=None, depth=0):
    if not start_length:
        start_length=len(lst)-1
    if not lst:
        return -1
    elif lst[-1]==what_to_find:
        return start_length - depth
    else:
        return lastindex(lst[:-1], what_to_find, start_length, depth+1)
```

i think this would do enough.

```
>>> lastindex([0,0,0,0,0,2],3)
-1
>>> lastindex([1,2,3,4,5,6],3)
2
>>> lastindex([1,2,3,4,5,1],1)
5
>>>
```